# Running classes in parallel in testNG

Tags: selenium, parallel-processing, testng

I have around 20 programs that need to be run in parallel using TestNG.

I am using TestNG and Maven framework for the same.

I have used the following

`<suite thread-count="20" name="Suite" parallel="classes">`

This opens up 20 chrome browsers.
However, my requirement needs me to open up 20 different browsers and login using the credentials (each browser needs username and password to login to the site)

What I am observing is that - it spins up 20 browsers but the username appends to the last (20th) browser.

Eg: Username is `test123`

The last browser gets the username as 
`test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123` (for 20 times)

and the login fails since the username is only `test123`

All the other 19 browsers do not have username populated and they are empty
Can someone help me? How do I make sure each browser logins with the username test123 separately and not append everything to a single browser?

Comment: U need to add the relevant code. Do u have a static driver?

Comment: Yes, it is  a static driver

Comment: Please find the code below-
Test.java

public class Test extends BaseTest{

 @BeforeClass
 public static void setupRunDetails() throws MalformedURLException
 {
  PreSetupTestConfigurations();
 }

 @Test(priority=1)
 public static void TC1() {

  try
  {
   invokeTestEnvUrl();
   loadDBPropertiesFile();
  }
}

Comment: public static void PreSetupTestConfigurations() throws MalformedURLException
 {
  runenv=System.getProperty("environment");
  Browser=System.getProperty("Browser");
  UserName=System.getProperty("UserName");
  Password=System.getProperty("Password");
  seleniumhub=System.getProperty("seleniumhub");
  if("local".equals(System.getProperty("selenium"))){
   launchBrowser();
  }else {
   selectBrowserRemote(System.getProperty("Browser"));
  }

  BaseUrl=getProp("config.properties").getProperty(runenv+PORTAL_URL);
  System.out.println("baseurl is "+ BaseUrl);

Comment: BaseTest 

public class BaseTest {

 /*Driver Declarations*/
 public static WebDriver driver;
 public static JavascriptExecutor jsDriver;
 public static NgWebDriver ngDriver;

 /*WebDriver Wait Declaration*/
 public static WebDriverWait wait;

 /*prop*/
 private static Properties prop;

 /** The service url. */
 public static String PORTAL_URL= ".portal.url";
/* PreSetup TestConfiguration Variables Declaration*/
 public static String environment;
 public static String BaseUrl;
 public static String Browser;
 public static String UserName;
 public static String Password;

Comment: with a static driver it will always refer to the last opened browser. U should look up [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) for storing driver instances. Refer to this [link](http://grasshopper.tech/732/) for pointers.